# DNN link two razor pages

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke

I am currently developing a razor module to DNN (Dotnet Nuke). In that I want to add a link to my main cshtml page to redirect another cshtml page with a parameter which located in the same folder. Could anyone suggest me a solution for that.

Thank you,
Nayanajith

Answer (score 0):

User a querystring parameter to do that.

Comment: Yes I tried but the thing is I used Globals.NavigateURL("Key", "Id=" + row[0]) for redirect. The given page is also in the module definition. But still it redirect to empty page which also not the page I wanted to redirect

Comment: What is the URL that was generated?

Comment: Hi Joe sorry for the late reply. I fixed it by my self the problem was in Globals.NavigateURL. The parameters which I gave was not in the correct format. Then I realized the correct format .  Ex: Globals.NavigateURL(TabId, "ControleKeyOfPage", ModuleIdForTheControleKey, Parameters)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.